# Excel equal sign sometimes won't make formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

In earlier versions of Excel when I would put an = sign I could do a formula such as:

= "Hello" & B2

and it would display as, for example:

Hello1234

In 2010 sometimes it does the above but sometimes it just displays the formula, for example:

= "Hello" & B2

I've ensured the cell formatting is the same as the one that works and it is.

This is very frustrating.

Anyone know what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This cell might be set as 'text'. It needs to be set as 'general'.

Rgds

Edit: I haven't seen you had checked the format, sorry.

Edit #2: Got curious and dig a while about your problem. Have you checked if B2 is also set as Text? It seems that when doing a direct reference to a cell, the cell format is also moved along with the value.

Try to add a function over the value (i.e. = `"Hello" & left(B2,1)`).

This idea came from [THIS](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/562740-formula-does-not-calculate.html) link.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, formats are the same.  Thanks for commenting though.

Comment: @user390480 improved my comment... hope it works now :)